# Which is the better non-empty array check condition and why?

Tags: javascript, arrays

This one's out of curiosity. Out of the two checks below for a non-empty array in JavaScript, which one is preferable and why?

1. `if(arr.length != 0)`
2. `if(arr.length > 0)`

Inasmuch as an array length can never be negative, up until now I have been using either without really bothering much.

Thanks!

Comment: Include `if (arr.length)` also :-)

Comment: I personally think that `if (arr.length > 0)` is preferable. You don't care about the case where there are no elements, and you already know they can't have negative elements. What you really care about is when the array has elements (i.e. length > 0)

Comment: Makes a lot of sense Hunter. Looks like everyone here is on the same page as to the question at hand! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's up to you; what do you prefer? There <s>shouldn't</s> won't be any (noticeable) difference "performance-wise" (so avoid micro-optimizations, root, evil and all such things).

Personally, for me that is, I find `arr.length > 0` conveys the idea more clearly (`more than 0 items in the array` v.s. `not 0 items in the array`. The `!` operator is (more) easily overlooked I guess and could cause confusion while possibly reading the code as assignment and also causes (very little but still) mental overhead of having to "not" the expression).

Having said that, any developer worth their salt shouldn't have any problem with either.

Comment: Before willing to ask this question, I felt inclined to use the "greater than zero" condition at a place in my code thinking along similar lines as you. Guess now I can rely on expert opinion as well. Thanks Roblll. :)

Comment: I'm being called expert! ♥ Where's my Expert badge? :P

Comment: Keep answering questions and spread your knowledge with repeated edits! That's the key! :P

Answer (score 0):

`if (arr.length)` is checking if there IS a length property and if, it checks if the length (if a number) is zero. `if (arr.length != 0)` is quite equal to `if (arr.length)`.

`if (arr.length > 0)` will include a mathematical operation (or something similar) because you don't only check for the existence of length and if it is maybe zero, you also check for the size.

In that case, `if (arr.length > 0)` is more precise but both does the same.